# How do I set up my android as extra monitor?

Tags: linux, android, multi-monitor

I'm trying to make my android tablet work as a second monitor to my laptop running Linux Mint. Since I want it to work as if i just plug in my monitor at home into VGA, I tried following the suggestions by chx in this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/28608/how-do-you-use-an-android-tablet-as-a-second-display. Specifically run `x11vnc -clip 1920x1080+1921+0` when preparing for the connection. With 'androidVNC' on my tablet I am able to establish a connection. But there the mouse pointer does not leave the monitor on my laptop and the and position of the display on my tablet is completely off to the right. So how do I make the tablet work as well as my desktop monitor at home with shared mouse and keyboard and drag and drop able?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to follow the steps in this post  https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=191555 to create a setup on VIRTUAL1 matching my tablet resolution. Then using `x11vnc -clip <appropriate resolution and offset>` or `x11vnc -clip xinerama<appropriate monitor number>`. This only suffers from a tiny bit of lag, and the general VNC issue that I must be connected to wifi. I wonder if it is possible to use my laptop as a hotspot and establish a direct connection either via that or using bluetooth, and in such way make it work in places without wifi.

Comment: Or you could use USB networking to diminish your lag.